# Where do the pink puzzle pieces come from?

Tags: puzzle-swap, streetpass-mii-plaza

In Streetpass Mii Plaza's *Puzzle Swap* game, there are pink pieces which cannot be obtained/bought with Play Coins. Nintendo has said that they can only be obtained through other players via Streetpass.

But if other players can only get their pink pieces from other players, when are pink pieces ever generated? How does the first pink piece become obtained by anyone?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first time a panel with pink pieces is unlocked, you will receive a free random piece, which can be a pink piece or a regular piece.

Apart from that, meeting other players with those pieces, or being a special employee at Nintendo, there is no other way to unlock them that comes to mind.

Comment: You can also get pink pieces from special Miis. They are sent from your plaza via Spotpass. The most recent was Shigeru Miyamoto's Mii, which was sent to promote Luigi's Mansion: Dark Moon about a month ago.

Answer (score 2):

When you get a streetpass from a Nintendo worker, they should have all the pieces, so you should be able to get a pink pieces.